# Default Android Time zone List

Tags: android, list, timezone

I was wondering if i can get somewhere the default code for time zone selection list for android version 2.3.3?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 11):

```
   String[] ids=TimeZone.getAvailableIDs();
   for(int i=0;i<ids.length;i++)
   {
       System.out.println("Availalbe ids.................."+ids[i]);
       TimeZone d= TimeZone.getTimeZone(ids[i]);
       System.out.println("time zone."+d.getDisplayName());
       System.out.println("savings."+d.getDSTSavings());
       System.out.println("offset."+d.getRawOffset());

      /////////////////////////////////////////////////////
      if (!ids[i].matches(".*/.*")) {
          continue;
      }

      String region = ids[i].replaceAll(".*/", "").replaceAll("_", " ");
      int hours = Math.abs(d.getRawOffset()) / 3600000;
      int minutes = Math.abs(d.getRawOffset() / 60000) % 60;
      String sign = d.getRawOffset() >= 0 ? "+" : "-";

      String timeZonePretty = String.format("(UTC %s %02d:%02d) %s", sign, hours, minutes, region);
      System.out.println(timeZonePretty);
      //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
   }
    ListView listitems=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
  ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,ids);
   listitems.setAdapter(adapter);
  }
```

The documentation for TimeZone.http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimeZone.html

To set time zone

Following is sample code for settings Time Zone of according to America

```
  // First Create Object of Calendar Class
  Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();        
  // Now Set the Date using DateFormat Class
  SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss z"); 
  // Finally Set the time zone using SimpleDateFormat Class's setTimeZone() Method
  sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles"));
```

Comment: Ok, i understood. But i would like to have less timezone entries. Something like this - http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/tividd/td/TWS/SC32-1274-02/en_US/HTML/SRF_mst273.htm

Comment: Have list of all timezone names and compare with timezone names you get from the loop. Filter and display the data.

Comment: @Jayesh `getAvailableIDs()` will get only the ids of timezones that is installed in the system. I am sure about that. What do you want more than the one that is posted here

Comment: getAvailableIDs() returns 577 timezones and in device when we set timezone it display 84 timezones in list, how can we get only 84 timezones ??

Comment: @Jayesh you are misunderstanding there is more than 84 hence you get 577 or whatever. the docs are right. you will get what is installed on the system no doubt about that

Comment: I have run the code in android device, it still return 577 timezones, this code returns java system's timezones but not android device's timezones

Comment: @Jayesh if still don't believe ask it on google devleoper forum i am sure the google engineers if they have time will answer. I am sure you get what is installed on system or else how will get displayed. I don't think you will get convinced. Sorry i can't help furhter

Comment: @Jayesh display this `for(int i=0;i<ids.length;i++)
   {
       TimeZone d= TimeZone.getTimeZone(ids[i]);`. display  `d.getDisplayName()` in the list you will know why you get 577

Comment: It return 577 because TimeZone.getAvailableIDs(); returns 577 ids, 
:D :D :D

Comment: bcoz your system has all those time zones installed :D :D :D. You see the difference because the default list does not display the same way. This does not mean what you get is wrong

Comment: you are giving useless comments, you can't solve my issue at all, :D :D :D

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately, Android settings takes that timezone list from an XML included in the Settings application. You can see this in the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/1.6_r2/com/android/settings/ZoneList.java) (line 161):

```
 private List<HashMap> getZones() {
     List<HashMap> myData = new ArrayList<HashMap>();
     long date = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
     try {
        XmlResourceParser xrp = getResources().getXml(R.xml.timezones);
     ...
 }
```

Other applications, such as Google Calendar, have their own arrays of values. It can be checked by doing [reverse engineering](http://adivishayam.blogspot.com.es/2012/05/how-to-extract-resouces-and-source.html) of those resources.

So, unless you want to maintain your own list (taking multilanguage into consideration...), I'd recommend you to have a reduced list of that provided by [java.util.TimeZone](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimeZone.html) and show only those timezones you want to, as @Raghunandan recommended you in his answer's comment.

Comment: https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_settings/blob/master/res/xml/timezones.xml

Comment: As @barn.gumbl has pointed out, R.xml.timezones points to an XML file with all the timezones located in res/xml/timezones.xml