# How to get All TimeZones of Android Device only?

Tags: android, timezone

I want to get timezones of Android Device,
I use TimeZone class of java.util.TimeZone,
TimeZone.getAvailableIDs() returs 577 and in Android Device only 84 TimeZones are available,

is any way to get device timezones ?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15542063/default-android-time-zone-list/15542223#15542223 if it helps

Comment: did you check the docs http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimeZone.html#getAvailableIDs(). `getAvailableIDs ()`


**Returns the system's installed time zone IDs**. Any of these IDs can be passed to getTimeZone(String) to lookup the corresponding time zone instance.

Comment: Ya, I have read documentation and I know that getAvailableIDs () Returns system's installed time zone IDs, but how can I get only device listed time zones ?

Comment: i used the answer in the link i posted and it works. so i don't know how it can display timezones not available

Comment: i am sure it displays only timezones available in the system. check your system time zones installed

Comment: I think you are not getting my question

Comment: i think you are not understanding the docs and the answer in the link